# I'm stuck, i can't pass data from model with api Rest, into another activity

Tags: api, rest, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I don't know why it's says me that "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"
I've been searching for this since 2 hours, and i don't know why there is this problem now, can you help me ? I want to pass data from apiRest into another activity with intent and putExtra/getExtra (I will do with firebase later, more simple and more easy way).

**Main Activity**

```
package com.mehdi.myapplication

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

lateinit var userAdapter: ListAdapter
var lm = LinearLayoutManager(this)
private val users: MutableList<Results> = mutableListOf()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    initView()
    getClassApiRet()

}
override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
    Toast.makeText(this, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailPageActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("email", users[position].email)
    startActivity(intent)
}

fun initView() {
    UserRecycleView.layoutManager = lm
    userAdapter = ListAdapter(this, this)
    UserRecycleView.adapter = userAdapter

}

fun getClassApiRet() {
    val retro = Instance().getRetroInstance().create(ClassApiRest::class.java)
    retro.getData().enqueue(object : Callback<ClassApi> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ClassApi>, response: Response<ClassApi>) {
            val users = response.body()
            runOnUiThread {
                userAdapter.setUsers(users?.results!!)
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ClassApi>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("Failed", t.message.toString())
        }
    })
}
}
```

**UserInfo**

```
    class ClassApi {

    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    val results: List<Results>? = null

}

class Results {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    val name: Name? = null

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    val email: String? = null

    @SerializedName("login")
    @Expose
    val login: Login? = null

    @SerializedName("picture")
    @Expose
    val picture: Picture? = null

}

class Name {

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    val title: String? = null

    @SerializedName("first")
    @Expose
    val first: String? = null

    @SerializedName("last")
    @Expose
    val last: String? = null

}

class Login {

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    val username: String? = null

}

class Picture {

    @SerializedName("medium")
    @Expose
    val medium: String? = null

    @SerializedName("large")
    @Expose
    val large: String? = null

}
```

**ListAdapter**

```
    class ListAdapter(val context: Context, val listener: OnItemClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.UsersViewHolder>() {

    private val users: MutableList<Results> = mutableListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListAdapter.UsersViewHolder {
        return UsersViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_user_list, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListAdapter.UsersViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindModel(users[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return users.size
    }

    fun setUsers(results: List<Results>) {
        users.clear()
        users.addAll(results)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class UsersViewHolder(item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item), View.OnClickListener {

        val UserImage: CircleImageView = item.findViewById(R.id.UserImage)
        val UserName: TextView = item.findViewById(R.id.UserName)
        val UserPseudo: TextView = item.findViewById(R.id.UserPseudo)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        fun bindModel(b: Results) {

            UserName.text = b.name?.first
            UserPseudo.text = b.login?.username

            val url = b.picture?.medium
            Glide.with(UserImage)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .fallback(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .into(UserImage)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(position)
            }
        }
    }
    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }
}
```

***Edit !!!***

I think the probleme is with the position and the interface, he can't get data.

```
ListAdapter

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val position = adapterPosition
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            listener.onItemClick(position)
        }
    }
}
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(position: Int)
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
    Toast.makeText(this, users[position].email.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailPageActivity::class.java)
    //intent.putExtra("lolipop", users[position].toString())
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look into clean architecture. Activity should never have to reference a model data class.

Comment: Okay, i will apply this in the futur, but now i'm stuck with this

Comment: My recommendation is that the sooner you switch, the better. You will only have more and more problems if you stick to this.

Comment: Okay, so i need to use mvvm architecture ?

Comment: Whatever architecture you prefer but use one. Google recommends MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response listener is passing the list of users to the ListAdapter, but it doesn't do anything to the MainActivity's `users` property, so that list remains empty. Then your item click listener tries to access the user by index in that empty list.

I would remove the `users` property from the Activity since there is no practical use for it. In your ListAdapter, change the `onItemClick` function of the OnItemClickListener to pass the actual User instead of the User's position in the data. You can get the actual User using the `adapterPosition` from within the adapter, since it owns the `users` list.

Edit: I'm suggesting to change your listener function signature to return an item directly. There's no reason the Activity should have to find the item in the collection when the Adapter can just provide it directly.

```
// ListAdapter:

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    listener.onItemClick(users[adapterPosition])
}

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(results: Results)
}
```

Comment: position and adapter position, are the same things, so i don't understand what you are saying. override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(position)
            }
        }

Comment: See edit for more explanation. Your problem is the Activity doesn't have a copy of the data to read from, but it shouldn't need to anyway since the Activity can pass the relevant data directly to the listener.